# ASP.Net - Call Method from markup that includes data-binding

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a user control in C# in ASP.NET. This user control has a method in the code-behind that is defined as follows:

```
protected string GetGreeting(string name)
{
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
  {
    return "Hello";
  }
  else
  {
    return "Hello " + name;
  }
}
```

My markup looks like the following:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="listRepeater" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" OnLoad="listRepeater_Load">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table id="listTable" style="width:100%;">
            <thead><tr>
                <th>Greeting</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
            </tr></thead>
            <tbody>    
    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td><%# GetGreeting("FullName")%></td>
                <td><a href='#'>view info</a></td>
            </tr>
     </ItemTemplate>

     <FooterTemplate>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

How do I bind the FullName property of the record in my data source? Right now, I keep seeing "Hello FullName". I want to see something like "Hello John Smith". What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your .aspx, you are calling `GetGreeting("FullName")`. This passes `"FullName"` literally.

Try

```
GetGreeting(Eval("FullName").ToString())
```

Answer (score 8):

The following should work:

```
<%# GetGreeting(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FullName").ToString()) %>
```

or a shorter form:

```
<%# GetGreeting(Eval("FullName").ToString()) %>
```