# Switching which data field is assigned to item repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been having a hunt around and I can't find out if this possible. What I have is an button (inside a repeater) and the text of this button is determined by a couple of values being returned in a dataset, like this:

```
Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "eventnumber") + "|" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "type" )%>'
```

But what I'd like to be able to do is switch what field gets assigned dependant on whether the eventnumber has a value in it. Something like this:

```
Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "eventnumber")!=""?DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "eventnumber"):DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "productid") + "|" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "type" )%>'
```

But I just can't seem to get it to work. (In this instance I get no errors but the text is empty)

Could anybody assist please?

Thank you,
Craig

Comment: Does `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "eventnumber"))` work?

Comment: try this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132578/asp-net-call-method-from-markup-that-includes-data-binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend to start using codebehind, [`ItemDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx) is the best place here:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        DataRowView row = (DataRowView) e.Item.DataItem;
        Button btn = (Button) e.Item.FindControl("ButtonID");
        object productID = row["productID"];
        object eventnumber = row["eventnumber"];
        object type = row["type"];
        if(DBNull.Value == eventnumber || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(eventnumber.ToString()))
        {
            btn.Text = string.Format("{0}|{1}", productID, type);
        }
        else
        {
            btn.Text = string.Format("{0}", eventnumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works a treat! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Well the easiest and most readable way would be to attach your repeater to event `ItemDataBound` and handle it there.

```
private void repeater_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) 
  {
     var item = (YourType)e.Item.DataItem;
     var label = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label");

     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.eventnumber))
     {
         label.Text = item.eventnumber;
     }
     else
     {
         label.Text = item.productid + "|" + item.type;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Tim Schmelter 

Right I'll give this a whirl. As a note there are loads of other stuff that are bound using the above method would I have to assign them all using the ItemDataBound method? Or can I leave the rest as they are?