# Define an Image url using QueryStrings

Tags: asp.net

Could someone help me define variable1 for Eval with Querystrings in ASP.net vb:

```
<img src="http://www.somewebsite.com?var1=<%# Eval("variable1") %> />
```

I can do it in php:

```
<img src="http://www.somewebsite.com?var1=<?php echo $variable1 ?> />
```

I just can not do it in ASP.net.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read the value from the Query String, probably you should use:`<img src="http://www.somewebsite.com?var1=<%= Request.QueryString("variable1") %> />`

Comment: Insert variable1 from ASP.net vb into the img src.  I do not want to take it from the current querystring.

Comment: @teledextri, if it's a variable, is there any reason why you can't just use `<%=variable1%>` after making `variable1` either `public` or `protected` in the code-behind?

Comment: @teledextri, freefaller is right use it directly or if is needed you can retrieve it from a method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7132578/asp-net-call-method-from-markup-that-includes-data-binding

Other option is to put this image inside control like repeater, which can be bound to a datasource.

Comment: Yes.  <%=variable1%> is what I am looking for now how do I get variable1 in Default.aspx.vb into Default.aspx where <%=variable1%> resides?

Comment: @teledextri, why have you confused the entire question by mentioning querystrings??  If it's a variable, then you make it `public` or `protected` in the inherited class, as I've already mentioned

Comment: usually this "variable1" resides in the code behind. In your case Default.aspx.vb, although you can define it in the Default.aspx. It is recommended to use Default.aspx.vb.

Comment: All yours @Hristo, I think we're fighting a losing battle, I'm outta here